# Prime number checker with two variable

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int n, i = 2;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 1)
        cout << "Not Prime";
    else
    {
        while (n > i)
        {
            if (n % i == 0 && i != n)
            {
                cout << "Not Prime";
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Prime";
                i = n + 1;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

i want to check prime number with only two variable ( without flag and counter ) and The code I have written for some number like 81 gives "Prime". what's wrong with it ?!

Comment: C# != C++. Please use correct tags

Comment: Use a function that returns `false` instead of displaying `cout << "Not Prime";` and `true` at the end of the loop

Comment: You set I to n+1 in the lower half of the condition which is wrong.

Comment: `bool prime(int n,int k=2){return n==k||(n%k&&prime(n, k+1));}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the program like this:

```
int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  
  for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
      std::cout << "Not Prime";
      return 0;                   // end the program     
    }

  std::cout << "Prime";           // must be prime if reached here
}
```

You can improve the efficiency by making the loop condition be `i * i <= n` as well, since you only need to check up to the square root of a number for factors.